# jquery script to run on loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting my scripts to run for content that has been loaded onto the page via .load().

In particular, how do you make a script that should run on .ready work?

Sample script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').fadeIn();
});
```

-- It runs fine on standard pages, but won't work for .load() sections.

Comment: where is the .load() happening ?

Answer (score 1):

You have no `slow` variable defined. It should be a string, so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

async functions come with a callback, use that to perform operations on the content once the `load` is complete:

```
$("yourElementSelector").load("url", function() {
    //load is completed, do work here
});
```

Comment: I'm hoping to find a solution other than callbacks.  I'm using a handful of .load'ed sections in place of simple links - having to put all relevant scripts into a callback on the original .load would be a mess

Comment: Ehh...when using async operations, callbacks or promises are why you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your event will only run when the page is first loaded and ready, any other event such as .load() will need additional event handlers attached.